# validate Username/Email REST endpoints HTTP method

Tags: rest, architecture

I'd like to add validate Username/Email valid/exists REST endpoints to my RESTful API. Right now I'm in doubt what HTTP method - GET or POST should I use for this functionality ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a service that verifies something using the HTTP method `GET` would be the most appropriate.  Essentially you are asking for an existing **resource** at it's current **State**, except the resource you are returning is the verification.